# curl download multiple files by date

Tags: curl, download, command

I would like to download multiple files from a site using a single curl command. Is there an efficient one line command to download all the files that have the same initial file path and/or have been uploaded after a particular date.

For example:

```
curl -O https://myURL/..../..../*
```

I know the "*" does not work but was wondering what would.

Alternatively to specify all files on that page uploaded past a particular date.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you change curl to wget? http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Retrieval-Options.html

Comment: Yes I technically can but I'm still not sure how to go about it (the files do not have the date within the file name)

Comment: You will not be able to tell if the file was created after certain date if you don't download it. There's an HTTP header for that: Last-modified.